# Display App version in App setting on IOS

Tags: objective-c, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap

How can I display the version of my Cordova App in the setting on iOS?

My build.xml file starts with the following:

```
<widget
  id="com.my-bundle-id"
  version="1.2.3"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
```

But in the App Settings only the permissions section is displayed:

[image]

How can I display the version section using Cordova?

(I looked around and found only a [plugin to programmatically get the App version](https://github.com/whiteoctober/cordova-plugin-app-version) but not how to populate the settings)

**UPDATE:**

What is missing is the **Settings.bundle** folders and files.

**How can I generate them using Cordova/PhoneGap/Ionic?**

Comment: This helps but it's not for Cordova: https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/adding-settings-to-your-ios-app-cecef8c5497

Comment: This plugin helps generate the Settings.bundle folder and files but it hasn't been maintained since 2017.. :( 
https://github.com/apla/me.apla.cordova.app-preferences